# python writing listing csv as columns

Tags: python, csv, listings

i want to write listings to csv as coloumns. 
Every listing have more then 100 output. I give example of csv below
thanks

```
   csv output example:
        coloumn 1            coloumn 2              coloumn 3  coloumn 4 coloumn 5
        listing 1_output1    listing 2_output1      ...         ...     ...
        listing 1_output2    listing 2_output2      ...         ...     ...
        listing 1_output3    listing 2_output3      ...         ...     ...
         ...                  ...                   ...         ...     ...   


import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import csv
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('http...').read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')



for listing in soup.find_all('div', class_='bigletter1'):

for listing2 in soup.find_all('td', class_='bigletter2'):

for listing3 in soup.find_all('td', class_='bigletter3'):

for listing4 in soup.find_all('td', class_='bigletter4'):

for listing5 in soup.find_all('td', class_='bigletter5'):
```

thank you for your answers
but also i have non-numeric class also like class_='models'
how can i write to in csv?

Comment: (Welcome to SO!) Can you get someone help you with English? As is, your post is hard to make sense of. Even with a spelling checker weeding out things like `coloumn` and `listining`, I can only guess that `listing` may be what I might call *list*, and `output` may mean *value* or *line*/*record*.

Comment: i mean outputs that are taken results from soup.find.all command.

Comment: Will all `listing`s have the same number of items?

Comment: @rademem You have two answers here. Do neither of them work for you?

Comment: its working, thanks alot coldspeed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `range` to iterate over each listing. Append to a `list`.

```
data = []

for i in range(1, 6):
    data.append([])
    for listing in soup.find_all('div', class_='bigletter{}'.format(i)):
        data[-1].append(listing.text)
```

Now, `data` looks somewhat like this -

```
[listing1,
 listing2, 
 ...
]
```

With each *column* as a sub-list. What we need is the transpose, to make it easy to write data to a CSV. This can be done with inverse `zip`. Use the `csv` module and write each row to a CSV file.

```
import csv

with open(file, 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    for row in zip(*data):        
        w.writerow(row)
```

Comment: (I'd think this answer great if I was confident rademem succeeds in figuring out how and why this `zip` works.)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually match all the desired elements in a single loop by having a "wildcard" locator:

```
for listing in soup.select('[class^=bigletter]'):
```

where `^=` means "starts with".